# ExtJs 3.4, How to refresh autoLoad in Ext.panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I need to refresh a panel that has autoLoad content.

```
var contentPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    border: false,
    plain : true,
    autoLoad : {
        url : 'content.html'
    }
});
```

I tried,

```
click : function(){
  contentPanel.getUpdater().refresh();
}
```

but it does not work.

anybody know how to refresh that panel content?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the click property defined?

Comment: i tested it,.. and works fine,.. the code inside click event is the correct way to refresh panel... i think the problem in somewhere else

Comment: //WarungNasi49 How did you do? did you do this way? contentPanel.getUpdater().refresh();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

```
contentPanel.autoLoad = {
    url : '/echo/js/?js=blahblahblah'
};
contentPanel.doAutoLoad();
```

or

```
contentPanel.body.getUpdater().update({
    url : '/echo/js/?js=blahblahblah'
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/Hz6dg/3/